# Add AWS Lambda SNS Destination via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sns

I have a setup where a lambda is triggered based on a timer. I want an email notification if there is failures with building the lambda. I have an email notification set up in SNS, and when I manually add the destination I can get an email for failed invocations.

[image]

I tried to add this destination configuration to my lambdas.tf file, but the destination is not showing up once the lambda is built.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function_event_invoke_config" "lambda_event_invoke_config" {
  function_name = local.lambda_function_name

  destination_config {
    on_failure {
      destination = "ARN"
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Open for alternatives (using python as lambda language) to achieve writing to SNS topic for email delivery on failure. The reason I haven't gone the route of writing a function like send_to_sns is because the project contains many lambdas and I wanted to avoid code duplication in like 30 different lambdas

Comment: I assume you're using the actual ARN of the SNS topic, and not the string `"ARN"`?

Comment: In your destination_config you have `destination = "ARN"` Is that your actual code? It should be referencing your resource or module that creates the SNS topic or a data source referencing the ARN such as:  `destination = aws_sns_topic.example.arn` OR `destination = data.aws_sns_topic.example.arn`

Comment: Yes, using the actual ARN. This does work, just checked too early while the function was still running. Thanks both!

ARN destination below in case it helps anyone else
destination = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn